# Paypal's Buttons not working properly( after I click it shows the window of paypal then it disappears immediately) Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal

After I click on paypal's Button , the window of paypal appears for 2seconds and then disappear [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EgnR.png)
I'm using this method : https://dev.to/alamriku/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-8-x-ba6
Also Using srmklive/paypal version~3
That's the console :
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrK5e.png)
This is the JavaScript Code :

```
<script

    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...&currency=USD" data-namespace="paypal_sdk"> 
  </script>




  <script>

    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal_sdk.Buttons({
 // Call your server to set up the transaction
             createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/api/paypal/order/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body:JSON.stringify({
                        'product_id': "{{$product->id}}",
                        'user_id' : "{{auth()->user()->id}}",
                        'amount' : $("#paypalAmount").val(),
                    })
                }).then(function(res) {
                    //res.json();
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    //console.log(orderData);
                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },

            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/api/paypal/order/capture' , {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body :JSON.stringify({
                        orderId : data.orderID,
                        payment_gateway_id: $("#payapalId").val(),
                        user_id: "{{ auth()->user()->id }}",
                    })
                }).then(function(res) {
                   // console.log(res.json());
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {

                    // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                  //  console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                    var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                    iziToast.success({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Payment completed',
                        position: 'topRight'
                    });
                });
            }

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

And here is my PaypalController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;
use App\Models\Payment;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $this->paypalClient->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
        $token = $this->paypalClient->getAccessToken();
        $this->paypalClient->setAccessToken($token);
        $order = $this->paypalClient->createOrder([
            "intent"=> "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units"=> [
                 [
                    "amount"=> [
                        "currency_code"=> "USD",
                        "value"=> $data['amount']
                    ],
                     'description' => 'test'
                ]
            ],
        ]);
        $mergeData = array_merge($data,['status' => TransactionStatus::PENDING, 'vendor_order_id' => $order['id']]);
        DB::beginTransaction();
        Order::create($mergeData);
        DB::commit();
        return response()->json($order);


        //return redirect($order['links'][1]['href'])->send();
       // echo('Create working');
    }
    public function capture(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $orderId = $data['orderId'];
        $this->paypalClient->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
        $token = $this->paypalClient->getAccessToken();
        $this->paypalClient->setAccessToken($token);
        $result = $this->paypalClient->capturePaymentOrder($orderId);

//            $result = $result->purchase_units[0]->payments->captures[0];
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            if($result['status'] === "COMPLETED"){
                $transaction = new Transaction;
                $transaction->vendor_payment_id = $orderId;
                $transaction->payment_gateway_id  = $data['payment_gateway_id'];
                $transaction->user_id   = $data['user_id'];
                $transaction->status   = TransactionStatus::COMPLETED;
                $transaction->save();
                $order = Order::where('vendor_order_id', $orderId)->first();
                $order->transaction_id = $transaction->id;
                $order->status = TransactionStatus::COMPLETED;
                $order->save();
                DB::commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            dd($e);
        }
        return response()->json($result);
    }

}
```

My routes :

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'paypal'], function(){
    Route::post('/order/create',[\App\Http\Controllers\Front\PaypalPaymentController::class,'create']);
    Route::post('/order/capture/',[\App\Http\Controllers\Front\PaypalPaymentController::class,'capture']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in the console is clear:

[image]

The URL you are fetching must exist, and it must return a valid JSON object with an `id` obtained from the v2/checkout/orders PayPal API.

If no id is returned, the behavior is as described -- the open PayPal window will close as there is no checkout to proceed with.

Comment: How to fix that ?

Comment: Implement a route that exists and returns the required JSON response with the id.

Comment: ANd how to return Json with the id ??

Comment: Create a route on your server that calls the PayPal API to create an order, and returns a JSON response that includes the id.  Have you read the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/ ?